# Memory leak in Mallet Alphabet?

Tags: java, mallet

I'm using Mallet 2.0.8 for topic modelling. The application loops over a set of documents and calculates a topic model for each of the documents (no information is to be shared among the passes or to be aggregated afterwards). Each pass constructs a fresh alphabet with `new cc.mallet.types.Alphabet()` for the current document.

However, it looks like the memory consumed by an alphabet cannot be garbage collected after each pass because it is referenced in `cc.mallet.types.Alphabet.deserializedEntries`. There seems to be a [question on the mailing list regarding this issue](http://mallet-dev.cs.umass.narkive.com/MMpCYaJ0/mallet-memory-leak), too.

As a workaround I'm using reflection and set the field `cc.mallet.types.Alphabet.deserializedEntries` to a subclass of `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<K, V>` just doing nothing when `putIfAbsent(K, V)` is called.

My questions are now:

1. Is this workaround safe for the described usecase?
2. Is it intended to construct an alphabet in each pass or is there a better approach that would not result in a memory leak?

Comment: are you getting an OutOfMemoryError?¿

Comment: Yes, `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`. The Eclipse Memory Analyzer blames `deserializedEntries` as leak suspect, too.